# What is the value of binary 100...(31 zeros) for 32-bit integer?

Tags: c#, java, bit-manipulation

It's just a random thought. 
The two's complement of 100...(31 zeros) is also 100...
So, the value must be 0. But we know that the binary representation of 0 is 000...

I know it can't be a -0 and a +0 because every binary representation should map to a unique value.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's −2<sup>31</sup>. Two's complement has only a single zero and the negative range extends one number further than the positive. And yes, that means that there is a single negative number that has no positive equivalent – this is sometimes called the [»weird number«](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#The_most_negative_number) since it is an exception of how two's complement numbers are built.

Answer (score 2):

It's the smallest possible value: −2<sup>31</sup>. It's not zero, because 100... is not zero. It's 2<sup>31</sup>.